# Operation Biting — composition of the German naval patrol

Tags: world-war-two, ww2-european-theater

Before the British paratroopers were rescued during [Operation Biting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Biting) in 1942, it was reported that a German naval patrol was operating nearby, which delayed the rescue of the paratroopers by the Royal Navy in the early morning hours of February 28.

What were the names of the ships that comprised the German naval unit? At 1:04:45 in [TIK's video on Operation Biting](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6EiOG_yvT04), he mentioned two German destroyers and two German E-boats but did not give the name of each ship.

Comment: Other accounts of the raid seem to mention one German destroyer and two E-boats, for example [Operation Biting](https://www.combinedops.com/Bruneval.htm):  "... _delayed by the presence of a German destroyer and two E-boats_"